# Is there a way to intercept AWT events at the head end of the system Queue?

Tags: java, awt, event-dispatch-thread

I have a graphics app and would like to (read only) be able to read events on the main event queue when they are deposited in the queue so they are not blocked by rendering.

Is there a way to do this when rendering in on the main AWT dispatch thread?

Since animation rendering with AWT doesn't work well outside the dispatch thread you get lots of jitter and other timing and thread switching issues when doing so.

But if the frame rate is slow one wants to abort low priority parts of the render when important events are waiting.

I have so far tried polling the system event queue using "peekEvent()" multiple times in the frame render.

I have also tried using the "push()" method on the system event queue to put my own in and override the "post" method, I get all my invocation events, and I get component events, but no key events.

arrrgh - seems with the push(new queue) method events posted to the head of the system event queue are forwarded to "postEventPrivate" which can not be overridden even in a application with full access :|

This may be an answer **if** "can't do that" is an answer.

seeking a way to get "out of band" key, mouse, and mouse wheel events.

Comment: *"read events on the main event queue when they are deposited in the queue so they are not blocked by rendering."*  Seems like you are going about this bass-ackwards.  (I suggest) Put the rendering in a different `Thread` & don't stuff with the event queue.

Comment: may ways.  But rendering with AWT doesn't work well outside the dispatch thread you get lots of jitter and other timing and thread switching issues.  But if the frame rate is slow then one wants to abort low priority parts of the render when important events are waiting.  like key input for certain keys or mouse clicks.  It appears even if I do multiple "peekEvent()" calls during a slow frame like if they are one frame every 3 seconds even when I hit multiple keys they don't end up being detected.  This is on windows and I havn't upped the priority of the dispatch/main thread.